# ABAC in microservices

Tags: abac

I am applying the ABAC methodology for access to protected resources.
My question is what is the best way to apply limits to certain fields that returns the api according to the user who is invoking it.
For example:

I want to allow access to /get-data to authenticated users, /get-data returns:
Date
Names
Address
Balance

I want to show the "balance" field only to users who are allowed access to view amounts, such as a counter.

Can I take balance as an attribute of the resource /get-data?